# Vue object passed through emit not recognized after listened in the other component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have two component say componentA and componentB.
In componentA I have a click event that triggers a method that passed the user object as the argument, and this object is then emitted using the event bus. When I successfully listened to the emit in componentB I have assigned the object that was emitted to a variable, I console.log out the variable it showed the object, but when I console.log again the variable outside of the Event.$once the object disappeared.
Any help would be appreciated :) 
Thanks!

Here's my code:

componentA

```
showUserStats(user) {
    EventBus.$emit('userInfo', user);
    this.$router.push({
      name: 'componentB',
      params: { id: user._id }
    })
  }
```

componentB

```
created() {
      EventBus.$once('userInfo', (user) => {
        this.userInfo = user
        console.log('userInfo', this.userInfo);
      });
      console.log('userInfo outside EventBus', this.userInfo);
    }
```

[Here is the image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuhMc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're console logging on `created` lifecycle event. The console log outside of the `$once` call is called immediately on component creation (when the user info isn't assigned) but the console.log inside the `$once` is happening only when the event is emitted and in turn the varible / data is assigned.

In line with comments: You can't just throw a delay in and expect it to work as it's based on events firing. You've not given us info on when `showUserStats` is called so I don't know when this event emits.

With regards to the computed value, that should work as it'll update when the user info is assigned but you'll need to add a check for when it isn't so, something like this:

```
computed: {
  fullName () {
    return this.userInfo ? this.userInfo.name + ' ' + this.userInfo.surname : ''
  }
}
```

It'll show blank unless the user info object has been assigned (note: You might need to alter the check based on how you initialise the `userInfo` var in data ())

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have tried giving a delay of 1 second still no luck :( 
I would like to use the variable in my computed method.

Comment: computed: {
      fullName() {
        return this.userInfo.name + ' ' + this.userInfo.surname;
      }
    }

Comment: The weird thing is, it works fine when I call the API to retrieve the user info

Comment: For what I understand, you're trying to trigger the event each time you click right? If so, then you should be using $on instead of $once